# Excel formula to merge multiple rows into multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I am trying to move data into separate columns and need assistance with a formula. I would like one row to display the multiple row data as in example row 2.

1. What I have so far that works:
   In column I  `=IF(A2<>A1,1,I1+1)` This numbers the rows according to how many same addresses.
2. At the bottom of the spread I create the following formula. 
   In cell A11    `=IF($I2=1,A2,"")`   copy formula down which shows the address only once which is great
3. In cell B11  `=IF($I2=1,B2,"")`    copy formula down, the address and loan # on same row, great
4. In cell C11 this formula don't work because I need to have column C2:H2 but no matter what I try not getting.   `=IF(OFFSET($I2,C$10-1,0)=C$10,OFFSET($C2,C$10-1,0),"")`      This put the file #'s but I need C through H for each in one row.

Any help with the formula so that I end with all the data in one row?
*FIRST TIME USER AND IT WILL NOT ALLOW ME TO POST IMAGES.

Column A address, Column B Loan #, Column C File #, Column D Order Date, Column E Paid $, Column F Paid Date, Column G Check #, Column H Company

Address1  Loan #  File #  Order Date  Paid Amount Paid Date   Client Check #  Company Name    NUMB    File #  Order Date  Paid Amount Paid Date   Client Check #  Company Name    File #  Order Date  Paid Amount Paid Date   Client Check #  Company Name
1001 STONEHAVEN ST  1899042109  9879    05-21-2018  575 06-15-2018  06152018    1st National Appraisal Source   1   11402   06-15-2018  150 06-30-2018  06302018    1st National Appraisal Source   12033   06-27-2018  150 06-30-2018  06302018    1st National Appraisal Source
1 NEW WAY CT    1899044139  14513   08-14-2018  475 08-31-2018  08312018    Platt Appraisal Company 1
1 NEW WAY CT    1899044139  15072   08-27-2018  150 08-31-2018  08312018    Platt Appraisal Company 2
1 Poco Paseo    1899041997  10269   05-29-2018  550 06-15-2018  06152018    Kersis Real Estate Appraisal    1
1 POCO PASEO    1899041997  10689   06-04-2018  390 06-15-2018  06152018    California First Appraisal Corporation  2
10 WOOD HOLLOW WAY  1899033554  11664   06-20-2018  600 07-15-2018  07152018    Metro-West Appraisal Co., LLC   1
10 WOOD HOLLOW WAY  1899033554  14520   08-14-2018  125 08-31-2018  08312018    Metro-West Appraisal Co., LLC   2
10 WOOD HOLLOW WAY  1899033554  14705   08-17-2018  100 08-31-2018  08312018    Metro-West Appraisal Co., LLC   3
100 HILLTOP LN  1899052576  14061   08-06-2018  400 08-31-2018  08312018    Klingensmith Appraisal Service, LLC 1
100 HILLTOP LN  1899052576  14740   08-20-2018  150 08-31-2018  08312018    Klingensmith Appraisal Service, LLC 2

Comment: post a link to the photo, or better yet post a minimal version of the table and expected output as text so we can copy paste.  Someone will help format it properly

Comment: There is no restriction on posting sample data and expected results in a code block that can be copied and pasted directly instead of retyping from an image.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula in K2, make sure you press ctrl+shift+enter when you enter the formula (since this is an array formula). Then drag down.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table4[Address], MATCH(0, COUNTIF($K$1:K1, Table4[Address]), 0)),"")
```

Enter this in L2, again, hold down ctrl+shift+enter when you enter the formula. Then drag down

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table4[Loan '#], MATCH(0, COUNTIF($L$1:L1, Table4[Loan '#]), 0)),"")
```

And keep going.

You say that you want C2:H2? What do you mean by that? You want this to be concatenated? If so just use a simple `CONCAT` formula at the end.

Comment: Row 3 Column A     1 New Way

Comment: 1. Row 3 Column A (1 New Way)  Row 3 Column B (1899044139 )  Row 3 Column C (14513)  Row 3 Column D (8/14/18) etc.   2.   Row 4 Column A (1 New Way)  Row 4 Column B (1899044139)  Row 4 Column C (15072) Row 4 Column D (8/27/18) etc.   3.   I need one row for each matching Column A with all the data in separate columns.  Like:  Row 3 Column A (1 New Way) Row 3 Column B (1899044139)  Row 3 Column C (14513) Row 3 Column D (8/14/18) Row 3 Column E (15072) Row 3 Column F (8/27/18).     4.  Making address rows vary from 1-4)  Column data for each row is usually 6 columns.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your statement in number 4, it seems you want to combine all details in columns C to H into a single cell IF it meets your conditions. In this sense, we can just pattern the formula to your approach in the previous formulas, and use the `TEXTJOIN` function to do this IF you have the latest version of Excel. Consider entering the following formula in cell C11:

```
=IF($I2=1,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,C2:H2),"")
```

This combines all your values under columns C to H and separate them with a comma and space (denoted by ", " at the start of `TEXTJOIN`).

If you don't have the latest version of Excel, a lengthy `CONCATENATE` function will do the trick:

```
  =IF($I2=1,CONCATENATE(C2,", ",D2,", ",E2,", ",F2,", ",G2,", ",H2),"")
```

For both formulas, should you want a different separator *(e.g use dash " - " instead of comma)*, then you just need to change `", "` to `" - "` for example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This formula results in combining only one row. I have duplicated addresses/loan #'s (usually no more than 4) lines.  I need to moved each row of data for that address into columns.  I edited my initial post per feedback to copy/paste as text.  I am hoping this helps.  When I try to post an image I get "Must have 10 reputations to post an image".  Again, thank you.